# Run script in SQLMode changing variables

Tags: sql-server

I have this code in a script file:

```
sqlcmd -E -I -S MyServerName -d MyDb1 -i D:\Updates\script.sql -o D:\Result\MyDb1.txt
sqlcmd -E -I -S MyServerName -d MyDb2 -i D:\Updates\script.sql -o D:\Result\MyDb2.txt
sqlcmd -E -I -S MyServerName -d MyDb3 -i D:\Updates\script.sql -o D:\Result\MyDb3.txt
```

I have more dbs to update but this is just an example, I have a .bat file that reads each sentence and execute the script.sql into each db, this works fine but now I'm generating scripts using SQL Data tools so visual studio generates the script for me, the problem is that it creates variables and put in a variable the db name, I need to be able to update that variable each time it goes to each db and run the script in sql mode.

This is an example of the script.sql for MyDb1:

```
/*
Deployment script for MyDb1

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;

GO
:setvar DictionaryData "DictionaryData"
:setvar DatabaseName "MyDb1"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "MyDb1"

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];
GO

PRINT N'Altering [cimpl].[LanguageView]...';

GO
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[LanguageView]
AS  
    SELECT l.LanguageLabelId, ll.[Name]
      FROM [$(DictionaryData)].[dict].[Language] l
     INNER JOIN [$(DictionaryData)].[dict].[LanguageType] lt
        ON l.[LanguageTypeId] = lt.[LanguageTypeId] 
     INNER JOIN [$(DictionaryData)].[dict].[LanguageLabel] ll
        ON ll.[LanguageLabelId] = l.[LanguageLabelId]    
      LEFT JOIN [cimpl].[LanguageConfiguration] lc
        ON (lc.[LanguageLabelId] = l.[LanguageLabelId]) 
       AND lc.[LanguageTypeId] = lt.[LanguageTypeId]    
       AND lc.[Active] = 1
     WHERE l.Active = 1   

GO
```

The script is much longer, but as an example, you can see the code is generated automatically but for MyDb1, now I need to run it on MyDb2 and MyDb3

How can I replace dynamically the sentence:

```
:setvar DatabaseName "MyDb1"
```

by:

```
:setvar DatabaseName "MyDb2" and :setvar DatabaseName "MyDb3"
```

at the time is running the sqlcmd?

Comment: `:setvar` commands within the script have the highest precedence so you need to supply the values during generation of each deployment script. This can be done with the `/variable` parameter for sqlpackage. Alternatively, remove the `:setvar` commands from the script and supply the values with `/v=value` paramters to sqlcmd.

Comment: Awesone!! works perfectly fine, thank you Dan